# Labels and Cross-referencing in items

Tags: cross-referencing, itemize

I have itemize environment and I want to cross-reference between two items. How do I do that?

Comment: Are the `\item`s in an `itemize` or an `enumerate` environment? LaTeX's cross-referencing mechanism works with objects that are associated with some counter variables: figures, tables, sections, footnotes, etc. enumerated list items will work, but not unnumbered ones.

Comment: I would wait for the OP to clear his/her intentions before closing.

Comment: No, I did not. The OP was prompted for closing several hours ago and then I added the comment above. Therefore, I did to vote for closing :)-.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to refer to all types of lists, is to use the packages [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) and [enumitem-zref](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem-zref/enumitem-zref.pdf). Then you may refer to all three types of list.

If you want to refer items in a bullet list, you have to set up `enumitem-zref` correctly. I have to refer you to the manual, which describes the set up in detail.

If you only want to refer to enumerated lists, you can do that easely with `enumitem`. Take a look at section 3 in the [`enumitem`-manual](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf), to find out how to set up references. You just give the item a `\label`:

```
\begin{enumerate}
   \item this is an item \label{itemone}
   \item this is an item \label{itemtwo}
\end{enumerate}
```

In the text, you refer to the items with `\ref{itemone}` and `\ref{itemtwo}`.

Comment: this does not work. the manual you recommended also does not have any section called set-up or like this

Comment: @user3352632 what exactly are you looking for? Code snippet works for me.