# Hyperlink jumping to wrong page if label is placed onto the next page

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, theorems

When referencing a theorem starting immediately on a new page with `hyperref` the page number is returned wrong and clicking on the link does not jump to the page the theorem is on.
The following MWE replicates this behaviour. It returns page number 1 for the theorem and when clicked on, it jumps to the end of page 1, although the theorem is on page 2.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-5][1-90]
foo \pageref{theorem}

\begin{theorem}\label{theorem}
 bar
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Including `amsthm` fixes the jumping but the page returned is still wrong. With `cleveref` this is reverted.
What can I do in order to have the reference point at the correct destination?

Comment: I think this is because of `itemize` environment. referring to it is meaningless.

Comment: [LaTeX's cross-referencing mechanism works with objects that are associated with some counter variables: figures, tables, sections, footnotes, etc. enumerated list items will work, but not unnumbered ones](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179452/labels-and-cross-referencing-in-items#comment414454_179452)

Comment: You need a \phantomsection command to set an anchor for the link.

Comment: @Fran \pageref makes sense also for unnumbered objects.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Of course, but must be at least one.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! Actually, my MWE was not correct. I have edited the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Do you really have a \pagebreak command in your document? If yes add an empty line after.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, I don't. Page 1 is full, foo is the last word on it. The page break is automatically handled by TeX. If I manually add `\newpage` it is correct.

Comment: Do you have an empty line before the theorem?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, there is no empty line before the theorem. If I add one it still is not correct.

Comment: It should work with the empty line, if not I need a real example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Fran Thank you! I have added it to MWE just now.

Comment: Try `\begin{theorem}\noindent\phantomsection\label{theorem}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  `\noindent` seems to introduce an extra space in the first line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Appending `%` after the label removes the extra space.